# Variables assigned in else clause not being passed via return in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue using Xcode 6.2 and Swift where I have a tuple that I am returning from a function. I have a subfunction that is running inside the function that is authenticating a user into our datastore and then returning the authentication tokens.  If the user does not authenticate, i.e., has an error, then I am returning that correctly to the calling function.  If the user passes authentication then I am only passing nil back to the calling controller even though I am making the same variable assignments.  Here is the code that we are using:

```
    func login(email:String, password:String) -> (uid: String?, provider: String?, error: NSError?) {
    var errorStatement: NSError?
    var provider: String?
    var testResult: String?
    var authData: FAuthData
    ref.authUser(email, password: password) {
        error, authData in
        if error != nil {
            // an error occured while attempting login
            println("error is:  \(error)")
            errorStatement = error
            testResult = "failed"
            provider = "Error"
        } else {
            // user is logged in, check authData for data
            testResult = "passed"
            provider = authData.provider
            userUID = authData.uid
            println("User uid = \(userUID) and provider = \(provider)")
            }

    }

    return (testResult, provider, errorStatement)


}
```

I am getting perfectly what I would expect when it has an error, but nothing when it is fine.  I know this is going to be some simple fix but I cannot seem to find it.  Thanks for  any help as I am new to this language.

Comment: Asynchronous code doesn't run synchronously.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, how can I get this to pass correctly then?  I have tried putting the return in the if-else blocks but get errors since there is no return in that function call and I cannot figure out a way to add a return

Comment: You can't have a return from a function if it runs asynchronously. You either need to call a delegate method at the end of the else clause, or have a completion handler in your function that you invoke at the end of the else clause.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar I will look into how to best incorporate that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code after I implemented the completion as suggested by @rdelmar

```
   func login(email:String?, password:String?, completion: (result: String?, errorDesc: String?) -> Void) {
    var errorStatement: String?
    var testResult: String?
    ref.authUser(email, password: password) {
        error, authData in
        if error != nil {
            // an error occured while attempting login
            println("error is:  \(error)")
            println(error.domain)
            errorStatement = "errpor"//error.localizedDescription
            testResult = "failed"
            completion(result: testResult, errorDesc: errorStatement) //send the calling function the attached information
            } else {
            // user is l ogged in, check authData for data
            testResult = "passed"
            userUID = authData.uid
            completion(result: testResult, errorDesc: errorStatement)//send the calling function the attached information
        }

    }
}
```